How to create an Index using QuantLib where the coupon reset frequency is different from payment frequency?
In the QuantLib python document, there is an example for creating a custom OvernightIndex:
name = 'CNYRepo7D'
fixingDays = 1
currency = ql.CNYCurrency()
calendar = ql.China()
dayCounter = ql.Actual365Fixed()
overnight_index = ql.OvernightIndex(name, fixingDays, currency, calendar, dayCounter)


In this example, a CNYRepo7D index is created as an OvernightIndex. But, the CNYRepo7D has a coupon reset frequency of 7 days, not daily. So the coupon should compound every week, not everyday. Is this example correct?
I then tried to use ql.IborIndex to model CNYRepo7D, where I created an IborIndex with a ql.Period(7, ql.Days). I also tried an IborIndex with a Period of 3M. But the result seems to be identical. I created a swap with a flat curve of 5% and print out the floating leg cash flow. All 3 indexes (Overnight, 7D Ibor, 3M Ibor) give me the same cashflow for the dummy swap.
What is the correct way to model a swap where its reset frequency is different from the payment frequency?
import QuantLib as ql

today = ql.Date(24,8,2024)

# create a flat curve of 5%
rate = 0.05
dayCounter = ql.Actual365Fixed()
interest_rate = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate))
flat_curve = ql.FlatForward(today, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate)), dayCounter)
curve_handle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(flat_curve)

currency = ql.CNYCurrency()
calendar = ql.China()


def print_floating_cashflow_given_index(index):
    # Add the fixing
    index.addFixing(ql.Date(23, 8, 2024), 0.05)
    # Create a 1Y swap with Quarterly Payment Frequency
    maturity_date = calendar.advance(today, 1, ql.Years, ql.Unadjusted)
    schedule = ql.Schedule(today, maturity_date, ql.Period(3, ql.Months), calendar, ql.ModifiedFollowing,
                           ql.ModifiedFollowing, ql.DateGeneration.Forward, False)
    schedule_len = len(schedule) - 1
    coupon_swap = ql.NonstandardSwap(ql.VanillaSwap.Receiver,
                                   [1] * schedule_len,
                                   [1] * schedule_len,
                                   schedule,
                                   [0.05] * schedule_len,
                                   dayCounter,
                                   schedule,
                                   index,
                                   [1.] * schedule_len,
                                   [0] * schedule_len,
                                   dayCounter,
                                   False,
                                   True)
    for cf in coupon_swap.floatingLeg():
        print(cf.date(), cf.amount())

# create Overnight Index
fixingDays = 1
overnight_index = ql.OvernightIndex('CNYRepo7D',
                                    fixingDays,
                                    currency,
                                    calendar,
                                    dayCounter,
                                    curve_handle)
print('Overnight Index Floating CashFlow')
print_floating_cashflow_given_index(overnight_index)

# create Ibor Weekly Index
ibor_weekly_index = ql.IborIndex(
    'CNY_Weekly',
    ql.Period(7, ql.Days),
    1,
    currency,
    calendar,
    ql.ModifiedFollowing,
    False,
    dayCounter,
    curve_handle
)
print('Weekly Ibor Index Floating CashFlow')
print_floating_cashflow_given_index(ibor_weekly_index)

# create Ibor Quarterly Index
ibor_quarterly_index = ql.IborIndex(
    'CNY_Quarterly',
    ql.Period(3, ql.Months),
    1,
    currency,
    calendar,
    ql.ModifiedFollowing,
    False,
    dayCounter,
    curve_handle
)
print('Quarterly Ibor Index Floating CashFlow')
print_floating_cashflow_given_index(ibor_quarterly_index)


Output
Overnight Index Floating CashFlow
November 25th, 2024 0.012465753424657534
February 24th, 2025 0.012543774790186646
May 26th, 2025 0.012543774790186868
August 25th, 2025 0.012543774790186868
August 25th, 2025 1.0
Weekly Ibor Index Floating CashFlow
November 25th, 2024 0.012465753424657534
February 24th, 2025 0.012543774790186646
May 26th, 2025 0.012543774790186868
August 25th, 2025 0.012543774790186868
August 25th, 2025 1.0
Quarterly Ibor Index Floating CashFlow
November 25th, 2024 0.012465753424657534
February 24th, 2025 0.012543774790186646
May 26th, 2025 0.012543774790186868
August 25th, 2025 0.012543774790186868
August 25th, 2025 1.0


That would be the use case for SubPeriodsCoupon but it turns out that the current implementation has issues: see https://implementingquantlib.substack.com/p/coupons-with-multiple-resets for an example.  We'll fix the problem in one if the next releases.
